# Final move of data after synchronising folders

Tags: windows, filesystems, synchronization

I am migrating six terabytes of data from legacy systems to new. The legacy data is stored in file vault application which retrieves files *very* slowly. Because of this it took six weeks to copy the data to the new source.  Due to the time it took to copy the data much of the copied data is now stale and needs to be updated.  The way I want to do this is by a final **move** of files.

Since the file source is so slow I don't want to move files which are the same on the source and destination, I only want to delete the source. I have not been able to find a product which acts in this way. In addition if the file is now an orphan on the destination, it needs to be removed as well.

I have tried RoboCopy: If you include same files, it copies the file again before deleting the source. If you don't include same files it ignores them leaving them on the source.  The later may work, though it doesn't give me good assurance that the destination files are up-to-date.  I have tried some other applications with similar results.

I am looking for a suggestion on doing this final file move to ensure that the destination contains all current files.

I cannot use a product like DoubleTake as the destination is an EMC VNXe, which I don't have access to, so I am unable to load any software on the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Use robocopy, normal behavior. Do a copy, no need for a move. Do the delete of the source afterwards.

Do verbose+logging, if you need proof that the files were copied or unchanged and thus not copied. That will be your assurance.

Comment: Also, if you want to remove orphans on the destination, set it to /MIR or /PURGE.  Finally, since it is an EMC product you may look at EMCOPY as well. https://mydocs.emc.com/VNXDocs/CIFS_Environment_Utilities.pdf

Comment: I have found it difficult to ensure all files have been copied. If the file count is different, it takes a lot of time time determine which one didn't get copied. Verbose+logging is difficult as there are around 12 million files, not sure how I would audit that with flat files.

Comment: There's a summary at the end; go with that. Verbose logging will show you what happened to any individual file if there's a question. There's very few shortcuts to take here; just do it and keep moving.